Strange CancellationToken behaviour
Im testing CancellationToken behaviour in my UserRepository. When I use cancellationToken from parameters and cancel query with postman this works without exception (and it really cancels query). It also works when I create CancellationTokenSource and cancel it manually but then I have the exception:
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.

No exception:
public async Task<List<UserDto>> GetAllUsers(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {   
        await Task.Delay(2000, cancellationToken);
    ...

Exception:
public async Task<List<UserDto>> GetAllUsers(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = source.Token;
        source.Cancel();
        
        await Task.Delay(2000, token);
    ...

Why are tokens handled differently?
UPDATED:
I HAVE an exception in first case but it is not shown in console for some reason. I can catch it:
public async Task<List<UserDto>> GetAllUsers(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("exception");
        }
        ...

It is probably catched somewhere else. May be someone can explain this.

"but then I have the exception:" - that looks pretty much exactly what I would expect; if it "works without exception" then... it didn't work? because if it had cancelled, we would expect a fault... so what are you seeing, if not a fault? does it complete and return zero users? or...?

If I cancel query with postman in the first two seconds code after await Task.Delay(2000, cancellationToken); is not executed. Thats why I said cancellation works.
After cancellation in postman I see... nothing. Like I didnt make the request. In browser it is just empty page.

From the documentation, we can learn that
If the cancellation token is signaled before the specified time delay, it will cause a TaskCanceledException exception and the task will be completed in the Canceled state. Therefore, when you manually call source.Cancel() inside the method, this will immediately mark the token as cancelled. When you call Task.Delay with this token, the task will detect that it has been cancelled and throw TaskCanceledException directly.
When a client such as Postman cancels a request, the cancellation of the task simply stops the execution without causing an exception.

When a client cancels a request, CancellationTokenSource.Cancel is also executed?
If so, why I have no exception when the client cancels request in time of first delay:
await Task.Delay(2000, CancellationToken.None); await Task.Delay(2000, cancellationToken);
Here the cancellation token is signaled before it is used.

In ASP.NET Core, when the client disconnects or cancels the request, the server's HttpContext.RequestAborted provides a CancellationToken. If the client disconnects or cancels the request, the IsCancellationRequested property of the CancellationToken becomes true, indicating that the cancellation request has been triggered. The asynchronous task on the server side can decide whether to terminate the operation early by checking this flag.

And by default, the framework does not throw exceptions because it assumes that many operations can be aborted normally without handling exceptions. Tasks can be canceled without explicit exception handling, which reduces the need for each part of the code to explicitly handle task cancellation.When using CancellationTokenSource.Cancel(), it is called manually, usually for server-side logic to actively initiate cancellation, so the framework expects you to check cancellation and perform related exception capture processing.
